# New property in iOS Core Data model is inaccessible from controller

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Core Data model with 3 properties and I've generated model class for that. It was working fine. Then I've added a new property(4th property) in that model and re-generated the model class file and replaced the old one. Now that new property is inaccessible from my controller. :( 
Could anybody please describe whats wrong?

Note: development environment is XCode 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do this without re-indexing the project?  If it's been open the entire time, it may not have noticed the changes.  Run Clean from the Product menu.